# Prevent PHP from entering input if fields aren't valid

Tags: php, forms, security

So here's my code

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxx", "s");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password1 = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
$password2 = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);

if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password1) || empty($password2))
    {
    echo "Complete all fields";

    // you can stop it here instead of putting the curly brace ALL the way at the bottom :)

    return;
    }

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    echo $emailvalid = "Enter a  valid email";
    }

if (strlen($password1) <= 6)
    {
    echo $passlength = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
    }

// Password numbers

if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password1))
    {
    echo $passnum = "Password must include at least one number!";
    }

if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $password1))
    {
    echo $passletter = "Password must include at least one letter!";
    }

if ($password1 <> $password2)
    {
    echo $passmatch = "Passwords don't match";
    }

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pass (Name,Username,Email,Password) VALUES ('$name','$username','$email','$password1')");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And what happens is the input is sent to the database even though the fields are valid. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? So say the my passwords don't match, it sill sends the form to the database. I want the PHP to stop doing that. Any ideas?

Comment: Check each of the validations individually and try to find out which one fails.

Comment: Put your insert query inside an else.Use elseif for all other if statements except the first one It will be like if(condition1){}elseif(condition2)elseif(condition3)...else(insert statement)

Comment: Another way is use exit inside each if statement.    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    echo $emailvalid = "Enter a  valid email";exit;
    }

Comment: How would I do that? @AmalMurali

Comment: @user3444414: Separate each one of your `if` statements and verify it works?

Comment: Your code is only as secure as the password method you're using.

Comment: Password method? I'll use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` I was more of referring to SQL injections. @Fred-ii-

Comment: You did not implement the answer you selected as correct as it is written. It should not use 'isset' it should use 'empty'. it then works as advertised. a minor point i agree

Comment: So replace `isset` with `empty`? @RyanVincent

Comment: that will make it execute the query when all the tests are true. It will fail if any are false. so yes, replace 'isset' with 'empty'. They are **not** the same as each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!(isset($emailvalid) || isset($passlength) || isset($passnum) || isset($passletter) || isset($passmatch))) {
    mysqli_query(...);
}
```

If any variable containing the error is present, then code between braces isn't running.

Comment: This would be secure?

Comment: If you secure your query before SQL Injection - yep

Comment: How would I secure it before SQL injection?

Comment: Read about prepared statements

Comment: Wouldn't this be a prepared statement?  `$name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);` Isn't that enough?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). And not, there isn't prepared statement.

Comment: What does this do if all the data is correct? i.e. every variable is set true. Does it execute the query? I suspect it is secure.

Comment: Yeah it inserts it into the database. I'm not sure if the `mysqli_query` is secure though? @RyanVincent

Comment: IMO it isn't secure. I would have used the PDO and its prepared statements.

Comment: Well PDO and Mysqli are both secure, its just a matter of how you use them.

Comment: Yes, but PDO is cross-platform and a little more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like:

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxx", "s");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password1 = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
$password2 = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);

if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password1) || empty($password2))
{
echo "Complete all fields";

// you can stop it here instead of putting the curly brace ALL the way at the bottom :)

return;
}

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo $emailvalid = "Enter a  valid email";
return;
}

if (strlen($password1) <= 6)
{
echo $passlength = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
return;
}

// Password numbers

if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password1))
{
echo $passnum = "Password must include at least one number!";
return;
}

if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $password1))
{
echo $passletter = "Password must include at least one letter!";
return;
}

if ($password1 <> $password2)
{
echo $passmatch = "Passwords don't match";
return;
}

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pass (Name,Username,Email,Password) VALUES         ('$name','$username','$email','$password1')");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You forgot to put the return; statement in every if.

Comment: But then that display a single error. Not multiple if you have any

Comment: So, you should not use return in the ifs but instead set a variable and afterwards check if it is set and return. This will echo all errors and return after that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

```
   if (!$name < '' || ....)
   {
     echo "Complete all fields";

     return;      
   }
```

Comment: Can you show me what one of _my_ `if`'s would look like using it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like im doing. So im preparing errors and if there is none i simply execute query if there are errors im showing them. Of course this is simplified but you should get the drill.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxx", "s");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password1 = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
$password2 = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']);

$canExecute = true;
$errors = array();

if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password1) || empty($password2))
{
    echo "Complete all fields";

    // you can stop it here instead of putting the curly brace ALL the way at the bottom :)
    return;
}

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $errors[] = "Enter a  valid email";
    $canExecute = false;
}

if (strlen($password1) <= 6)
{
    $errors[] = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
    $canExecute = false;
}

// Password numbers

if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password1))
{
    $errors[]= "Password must include at least one number!";
    $canExecute = false;
}

if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $password1))
{
    $errors[] = "Password must include at least one letter!";
    $canExecute = false;
}

if ($password1 <> $password2)
{
    $errors[]= "Passwords don't match";
    $canExecute = false;
}

if ($canExecute)
{
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pass (Name,Username,Email,Password) VALUES         ('$name','$username','$email','$password1')");
    mysqli_close($con);
}
else
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($errors as $error)
        echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```